# Cannot add a new article in a simple blog built with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have built a simple blog with React. I am having an issue, whenever I try and add a new article. I get the below error.
TypeError: **Cannot read property 'upvotes' of null**

The article page code is below:

```
const ArticlePage = ({ match }) => {
    const name = match.params.name;
    const article = ArticleContent.find(article => article.name === name);

    const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] = useState({ upvotes: -1, comments: [] });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await fetch(`/api/articles/${name}`);
            const body = await result.json();
            setArticleInfo(body);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [name]);

    if (!article) return <notFoundPage />

    const otherArticles = ArticleContent.filter(article => article.name !== name);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{article.title}</h1>
            <UpvotesSection articleName={name} upvotes={articleInfo.upvotes} setArticleInfo={setArticleInfo} />
            {article.content.map((paragraph, key) => (
                <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
            ))}
            <CommentsList comments={articleInfo.comments} />
            <AddCommentForm articleName={name} setArticleInfo={setArticleInfo} />
            <h3>Other Articles:</h3>
            <ArticlesList articles={otherArticles} />
        </>
    );
}
```

That is where the error tells me to look. I have tried to comment the upvotes section out, it just changes the error to comments. I comment them both out and the article renders but it has no comments or upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because your `articleInfo` is `null`.
That's why it doesn't find `upvotes` or `comments` in your `return` method.

Your initial state contains an object `{ upvotes: -1, comments: [] }`. So that's not the problem. The only place where this can go wrong is where you call `setArticleInfo`.

Have you tried logging your `body` variable?
My guess is that your `body` variable is `null`, and by calling `setArticleInfo(body)` you set your `articleInfo` to be `null` hence why it throws an error.

Comment: So after some playing around I commented out setArticleInfo and got the page to show. Although the server is giving me a 500 (internal server) error. Then after doing ```db.articles.find()``` I realised that the new articles are not showing. So the server is looking for comments and upvotes on an article that doesn't exist.

Comment: Great, we found the culprit, looks like this is a backend problem rather than a frontend problem